# what is structured data SD-ID and SD-PARAMS in rsyslog?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, logrotate, syslog-ng, log-rotation

we have structured data SD-ID and SD-PARAMS paramenters in rsyslog.I am not getting how it works from where these parameters takes value.Can someone explain me what these things are?